# form input element with square bracket

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In my form I have an element with square bracket:

```
<input name="bodyIDList[]" id="bodyIDList" value="">
```

When I pass this page to ColdFusion how is this treated as a form variable? As a list or an array?

Comment: Voting this down because - as per Peter's answer - this question demonstrates no investigation at all.

Comment: It would have taken you less time to check it yourself than to ask. ;) I didn't downvote though, seems like it's downvoted enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you are asking this question - it takes literally a few seconds to create a test and find out for yourself!

The code to test it is this simple:

```
<cfoutput>
    <form action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
        <input name="bodyIDList[]" id="bodyIDList" value="">
        <button type="submit">go</button>
    </form>
</cfoutput>

<cfdump var=#Form# />
```

Run that, press go, look at the dump.

But, since we've now got this question here, I might as well give a full answer, since there is actually an interesting thing to be aware of...

If you run that code on Adobe ColdFusion 9 (or any other version of CF) you will get a string variable named `bodyIDList[]` - that is `Form['bodyIDList[]']` - with a single value.

If you had multiple of these fields you will still get a string with a comma-delimited list.

Since it contains brackets in the variable name, it is not possible to access this field with dot-notation.

All the above also applies for the latest [Open BlueDragon](http://www.openbluedragon.org).

However, if you use [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org), you will get a different behaviour (copied from PHP) which instead will give you a variable called `bodyIDList` - i.e. Form['bodyIDList'] with no brackets - which contains an **array**

If you had multiple of these fields you would get a single array with multiple elements.

There is currently no admin configuration option to make Railo compatible with ACF on this, so:
**If you are writing cross-engine CFML code, do not use form field names with brackets.**
*(well, unless you're aware and willing to deal with the differences).*

Comment: +1 for Railio... not something I have configured. I also agree that some simple research could have provided a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

The element will be listed individually, e.g. as bodyIDList[]. I just checked this on one of my CF9 boxes.

Now, if you had multiple fields of the same name, it would appear as a list in the form scope.